# Android Wear Recycler View Effect

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I spent few days trying to figure this out and I still cannot. How can I achieve such layout with WearableRecyclerView?

[image: what I need to achieve]

I am making new version of our application for wear 2.0. We achieved such effect before but with components that are now deprecated (old WearableRecyclerView). New implementation seems to work in a different way and the problems are:

- I cannot set solid background for items by applying it to every item in recycler (they have a lot of space between them and screen insets and I cannot do anything about it)
- I cannot make recycler wrap its height either - it crashes
- Finally I have no idea how to make first item move to the middle of the screen and leave offset atop.

Will appreciate any help :)

Comment: have you figured out how to implement this?

Comment: @pushandpop I did. I don't have access to this code right now, but I had to do hacky things with view holders width/height/translations/paddings or something. In general, you want your recycler to have its background and padding (this will allow you to have this extra space and chosen color). Then you want your view holders to be that tight and that sized to simulate another background.

Comment: Could you show me reason what you did ?

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka hi, unfortunately, I cannot, I wrote this app in my previous company and I have no longer access to this code. All I can say is in the comment above. I played around with padding and translating view holders and recycler itself until I achieved desired effect